# stm32f7 https connection using with mbedtls

Tags: c, stm32, ethernet, mbedtls

my connnection is return -0x0050 on ssl_tls step.

```
  < Read from server:../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:8270: => read<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:4311: => read record<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:2536: => fetch input<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:2696: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:2720: in_left: 0, nb_want: 5<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:2722: ssl->f_recv(_timeout)() returned -80 (-0x0050)<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:4973: mbedtls_ssl_fetch_input() returned -80 (-0x0050)<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:4344: ssl_get_next_record() returned -80 (-0x0050)<\n>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:8335: mbedtls_ssl_read_record() returned -80 (-0x0050)<\n>
```

I tried to connect google.

I tried change heap size. I tried connect to other website etc.

Comment: This is an embedded related issue. We need way more code and context to understand what is going on and help you solve the issue.. `0x0050` means `MBEDTLS_ERR_NET_CONN_RESET`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.